# Force create an eloquent model through a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.3

In a small project with Laravel 5.3 and Stripe, I am trying to force create a `Subscription` on a `User` through a `hasOne` relationship:

```php
// User.php
public function subscription() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Subscription');
}

public function subscribe($data) {
    return $this->subscription()->forceCreate(
        // $data contains some guarded fields;
        // create() will simply ignore them...
    );
}
```

However, I get :

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::forceCreate()

Even though `forceCreate()` is a [valid Eloquent method](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_forceCreate).

Any ideas how I can simulate this behavior? Or should I just `save` a `Subscription` manually assigning each field? The complication is that certain fields should be kept `guarded`, e.g. `stripe_id`.

#### EDIT

My quick' n' dirty solution:

```php
// User.php @ subscribe($data)
return (new Subscription())
        ->forceFill([
            'user_id' => $this->id,
            // $data with sensitive guarded data
        ])
        ->save();
```

I'm sure there is a better way though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `$this->subscriptions()` returns an instance of [`HasMany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php) class, not a [`Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php).

Contrary to [`create`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L317) and [`createMany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L337), there's no `forceCreate()` implemented in [`HasOneOrMany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php) class. And thus, there's no first-hand API to use in such situations.

You see? when you call `$this->subscriptions()->create()`, you're calling the `create` method on a `HasMany` instance, not a `Model` instance. The fact that `Model` class has a `forceCreate` method, has nothing to do with this.

You could use the [`getRelated()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2283) method to fetch the related model and then call `forceCreate()` or `unguarded()` on that:

```php
public function subscribe($data) {
    return $this->subscription()
                ->getRelated()
                ->forceCreate($data);
}
```

But there's a serious downside to this approach; it does not set the relation as we're fetching the model out of the relation. To work around it you might say:

```php
public function subscribe($data)
{
    // $data['user_id'] = $this->id;
    // Or more generally:  
    $data[$this->courses()->getPlainForeignKey()] = $this->courses()->getParentKey();

    return $this->courses()
                ->getRelated()
                ->forceCreate($data);
}
```

Ehh, seems too hacky, not my approach. I prefer unguarding the underlying model, calling `create` and then reguarding it. Something along the lines of:

```php
public function subscribe($data)
{
    $this->courses()->getRelated()->unguard();

    $created = $this->courses()->create($data);

    $this->courses()->getRelated()->reguard();

    return $created;
}
```

This way, you don't have to deal with setting the foreign key by hand.

laravel/internals related discussion:
[[PROPOSAL] Force create model through a relationship](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/356)